# Groupby in Pandas not working

Tags: python, pandas

Data
Multiple rows per ID

```
ID Value1 Value2
1    1     0
1    0     1
1    3     1
```

Desired output

For each ID, SUM(Value1)-SUM(Value2).

In this case it would be 4-2=2 for ID1.

I want the result to be placed back in the original table like below

```
ID Value1 Value2 Calculated_Value
1    1     0        2
1    0     1        2
1    3     1        2
```

I have tried this..it ran but I got NaN in the output table..

```
df['Calculated_Value']= df.groupby(['ID'])['Value1'].sum()-df.groupby(['ID'])['Value2'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `groupby` operations, and differences between `groupby` operations, are `pd.Series` with index defined by grouper column(s), in this case `ID`.

Therefore, use `pd.Series.map` with `ID` to extract groupwise results.

```
df['Calculated_Value'] = df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID')['Value1'].sum() - \
                                      df.groupby('ID')['Value2'].sum())
```

Comment: Thanks! @jpp, is the '\' after the minus sign a typo?

Comment: @babz, the \ just signifies line continuation. Not necessary here, but just putting it there for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have similar indexes between the two frames, when you groupby in the second set, you create the index as ID

```
# Set the index first
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

# Now when we calculate, we can 'left join' onto the correct index values
df['Calculated_Value'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Value1'].sum()-df.groupby(['ID'])['Value2'].sum()
```

Comment: Just remember to `reset_index` afterwords if you want OP's desired output.